# How do I know if a program I run as a child process of VS Code is still running on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I have code that tests 6 sorting algorithms in three different ways each. They sort more than 600000 thousand words in an array of strings.

While I was waiting for it to finish execution, my laptop was turned off for, I think, 3 minutes due to inactivity. I gave my mouse a shake, and it turned back on.

I went to task manager to see if VS Code is still running the code, but I can't tell from there. Also, the terminal will only output the results at the very end of the code, so I don't see any clues on that from there too.

Comment: Thanks, I see some java.exe files that say "running" in the task manager. They have as description "OpenJDK Platform binary" .... They are also both consuming 34% of the total usage of the CPU. I think that's the clue that the code is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Task Manager for the name of the program / commandline command that was used to run the program. If your program is run through a virual machine or interpreter, look for the name of the virtual machine or interpreter in the Task Manager list of processes.

You'll find it helpful to view processes in your Task Manager or similar application as a tree of parent/child process relationships. The Windows Task Manager can't do that, so you'll need to install and use the Windows [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) application instead. Then you can look for processes that are children of the `code` executable (VS Code).